# Pandas: map dataframe column to list and assign binary value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.read.csv("variants.csv")
print(df)
    Sample Position Reference Alt
    Sample1 123 C T
    Sample2 123 C T
    Sample3 1234 C G
```

and a list of 'Positions' of interest:

```
pos = [123, 1334, 1443, 133]
```

I want to map the column of 'Position' to my list and create a new column in the dataframe where if 'Position' exists == 1 else I assign a value of 0. Example:

```
        Sample Position Reference Alt Value
        Sample1 123 C T 1
        Sample2 123 C T 1
        Sample3 1234 C G 0
```

How can I do this in Pandas or another way? Apologies as I'm a beginner to python.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for mask and then convert to `1,0` from `True, False` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Value'] = df.Position.isin(pos).view('i1')
```

Or by cast to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Value'] = df.Position.isin(pos).astype('int')
```

Or with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df.Position.isin(pos), 1, 0)
```

Comment: never seen `view` before, nice!